# SharePoint 2007 SP2 and people picker one way trust domains

Tags: 2007

*Peoplepicker checknames respects the peoplepicker-searchadforests property after SP2. This was not the case prior to SP2.

**After SP2 you will not be able to
   lookup users in an external domain
   that is in a one-way trust
   relationship with the sharepoint
   local domain.**

Prior to SP2 the Peoplepicker Checknames function did not respect the peoplepicker-searchadforests property. Users could be resolved from other domains, even if there was only a one way trust.
Checknames used LSAT and LDAP to search and display a match prior to build 12.0000.6520.5000 as described in KB976396: http://kbalertz.com/Feedback.aspx?kbNumber=976396 (http://kbalertz.com/Feedback.aspx?kbNumber=976396)*

**IS THIS REALLY TRUE?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the property honoring, however once the properties are correctly set you will be able to resolve names.

Referenced Article
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2384424

I believe KB976396 is simply the description article for WSS CU for Oct 2009 which will turn off resolution for NT4 Domains.  I think you are confusing the two.

SUMMARY
WSS/SharePoint 2007 SP2 can still utilize one way trusts if configured properly

The ONLY thing that wont resolve will be if you applied the Oct09 CU, and that would only be trusted NT4 domains.  This is usually only an issue when you have mixed forest, with NT4 domains as part of the transitive trust.  If you were explicitly trusting an NT4 Domain, than you wouldn't apply the CU (that would break the point of the trust)